# Hard drive reporting wrong size

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, fdisk

I have a 1TB Hitachi drive that has been working just fine.  I had to repartition it into vfat because a co-worker's Mac drive was dying and I needed to copy what I could.  He took the 1TB drive home and plugged it into his Mac.  After that, the driver reports that only 33.10 MB is available.  I've tried to reset with fdisk, gdisk, and (g)parted, and what hdparm says.  I've not been able to find any way to get back the missing space.  The missing space is not reported as empty space.  It only indicates that there's 33.10 MB on the drive.  On my Linux box, this was plugged in to a SATA port.  I looked at it on USB on a Mac and Windows and still only 33 MB reported.  I've tried setting CHS params.

```
ATA device, with non-removable media
Model Number:       Hitachi HDS721010CLA332                 
Serial Number:      JP
Firmware Revision:  JP4OA3EA
Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6; Revision: ATA8-AST T13 Project D1697 Revision 0b
Standards:
Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x0029) 
Supported: 8 7 6 5 
Likely used: 8
Configuration:
Logical     max current
cylinders   64  64
heads       16  16
sectors/track   63  63
--
CHS current addressable sectors:      64512
LBA    user addressable sectors:      65134
LBA48  user addressable sectors:      65134
Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes
device size with M = 1024*1024:          31 MBytes
device size with M = 1000*1000:          33 MBytes 
cache/buffer size  = 29999 KBytes (type=DualPortCache)
Form Factor: 3.5 inch
Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 7200
Capabilities:
LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
Queue depth: 32
Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 16
Advanced power management level: disabled
DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
     Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
     Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
```

Answer (score 1):

Some times there is possibility for Linux file system to get corrupted when connecting to  mac. Try recovering it using below command

```
fsck -a /dev/sda1

fsck -y /dev/sda1
```

(OR)

```
sudo dosfsck -w -r -l -a -v -t /dev/sda1
```

Note: Also please connect the drive to Mac and check whether it showing right space in mac if above not working

Comment: There are no partitions on the drive.

Comment: Though we have not created any partitions. The whole drive will be shown as a single partition like sda1 or sdb1. check it with parted -l command and try running the above command

Comment: There are no partitions.  There is no /dev/sdd1 in /dev, just /dev/sdd.  Can't fsck /dev/sdd because there's nothing on the drive.  parted -l lists nothing on the drive either: